# Pycharm module numpy not found even though seeing numpy in Project Interpreter

Tags: numpy, pycharm

I am installing 3rd party software for a new installation of Pycharm on MacOS. When I run my python file I am still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' even though:

I have installed numpy using the New Project Preferences / Project Interpreter dialogue. When I did this, **the statement import numpy no longer has red highlights**, suggesting that the compiler has resolved the import statement, and I can also see numpy in the list of packages in the same Project Interpreter dialogue.

What other steps can I try?

Comment: You run it in the terminal or the console?
If the problem happens in the console, check that the Python interpreter is also well set in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console`